# Making list item sizes consistant

Tags: android

I have an issue where the sizes of list items vary depending on if the phone is 21+ or not.

How can it make it so devices that are pre-21 have the same spacing between items?

List:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:divider="@color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_transparent"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="false">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3.5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="1.7dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you know a solution I would be very grateful. Thanks

Here is a picture of what I mean:

[Picture of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRkvh.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to how shadows are drawn on different API levels. In 21+, the shadow is drawn *outside* the view itself, whereas on older levels it has to be drawn *inside* the view's bounds. The support library adds padding to the `CardView` on these older API levels in order to have room to draw the shadow.

You can add this attribute to your `<android.support.v7.widget.CardView>` tag to make them behave the same, regardless of API level:

```
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html):

> Before Lollipop, CardView adds padding to its content and draws shadows to that area.

and

> Alternatively, If you want CardView to add inner padding on platforms Lollipop and after as well, you can call setUseCompatPadding(boolean) and pass true.